# Determine target service/method from CXF Interceptor

Tags: java, cxf

I'd like to write an interceptor for the Apache CXF JAX-RS implementation that inspects the target service/method for a particular annotation and does some special processing for that annotation.

I can't seem to find anything in the interceptor documentation that describes how to do this. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah. I didn't specify that I was using the JAX-RS part of CXF; not sure if that impacts Daniel Kulp's answer but his solution didn't actually work for me. I believe it is because CXF does things differently when handling JAX-RS.

I came across the source for CXF's `[JAXRSInInterceptor][1]` and I saw in that code that this interceptor is putting the method info into the `Exchange` object like so:

`message.getExchange().put(OperationResourceInfo.class, ori);`

...during the `UNMARSHAL` phase, which according to the [CXF interceptor docs](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/interceptors.html) happens before the `*_LOGICAL` phase. So by writing an `Interceptor` that handles the `USER_LOGICAL` phase I can do:

`message.getExchange().get(OperationResourceInfo.class)`

...to get access in there to the `Method` and `Class<?>` of the `Service` handling the call!

Comment: This will return wrong results if you are using sub-resources! The ORI returned will be the one used to select the sub-resource locator method, but not the acutal handler method

Comment: Works perfectly, if you need the method name just use `operationResInfo.getMethodToInvoke().getName();`

Comment: And if you need the class use `operationResInfo.getMethodToInvoke().getDeclaringClass()`

Answer (score 11):

If the interceptor runs fairly late in the chain (like the USER_LOGICAL 
phase), you should be able to do something like:

```
Exchange exchange = msg.getExchange();
BindingOperationInfo bop = exchange.get(BindingOperationInfo.class);
MethodDispatcher md = (MethodDispatcher) 
                exchange.get(Service.class).get(MethodDispatcher.class.getName());
Method meth = md.getMethod(bop);
```

That should give you the Method that was bound in so you can get the declared 
class or the annotations, etc...

Comment: Aha, that's the sort of thing I was looking for, but I guess I didn't know the terminology in CXF to traverse the classes. :) I'll give that a shot, thanks!

Comment: MethodDispatched is deprecated. Can you please suggest any other alternative? I am using PRE_STREAM & RECEIVE phases

Answer (score 1):

It has been quite some time since the accepted answer. But there are a few supporting abstractions provided in the

```
cxf-rt-core-2.7.3.jar
```

One in there that is provided is `org.apache.cxf.interceptor.security.AbstractAuthorizingInInterceptor`

This sample excerpt from the source might be a good reference:

```
protected Method getTargetMethod(Message m) {
    BindingOperationInfo bop = m.getExchange().get(BindingOperationInfo.class);
    if (bop != null) {
        MethodDispatcher md = (MethodDispatcher) 
            m.getExchange().get(Service.class).get(MethodDispatcher.class.getName());
        return md.getMethod(bop);
    } 
    Method method = (Method)m.get("org.apache.cxf.resource.method");
    if (method != null) {
        return method;
    }
    throw new AccessDeniedException("Method is not available : Unauthorized");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Building off the original interrogator's answer, I came up with this

```
public UserContextInterceptor() {
    super(Phase.USER_LOGICAL);
}

@Override
public void handleMessage(Message message) {
    if(StringUtils.isEmpty(getHeader("some-header-name", message))) {
        final Method method = getTargetMethod(message);
        if(isAnnotated(method.getDeclaringClass().getAnnotations()) || isAnnotated(method.getAnnotations())) {
            final Fault fault = new Fault(new LoginException("Missing user id"));
            fault.setStatusCode(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
            throw fault;
        }
    }
}

private static Method getTargetMethod(Message message) {
    final Exchange exchange = message.getExchange();
    final OperationResourceInfo resource = exchange.get(OperationResourceInfo.class);
    if(resource == null || resource.getMethodToInvoke() == null) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException("Method is not available");
    }
    return resource.getMethodToInvoke();
}

private static boolean isAnnotated(Annotation[] annotations) {
    for(Annotation annotation : annotations) {
        if(UserRequired.class.equals(annotation.annotationType())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```